# Visualflow Issue

Tags: flow, visual-workflow, visual-flows

I am calling a visualflow through Process builder on Opportunity edit.

[image: Process builder]

Want to call a flow to create order for a OpportunityID then I don't find this   "OpportunityId" field in the list.

[image: Flow Record Create]

But when I check the field in order, I do see Opportunity LookUP field.

[image: Flow Record Create]

Can you please let me know why it is not visible in Visualflow Record Create.

Comment: Check the field accessibility as by default it seems to be set to Hidden for all Profiles.

Comment: Is this something related to this? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69288/field-not-showing-in-process-builder

Answer (score 1):

I think this may just be permissions as I tested this in a Dev Org and the Opportunity lookup is hidden from all users by default. Then when I added it to the order page layout and gave the accounts permission to edit it it was visible in the Flow for the Create Record function on Orders.